# How do I prevent testify command line args from leaking into my Cobra application?

Tags: go, go-cobra, go-testing, testify

This is my test:

```
// A test of TestSuite
func (ts *TestSuite) TestMyThing() {
    cmd := RootCmd()
    b := bytes.NewBufferString("")
    cmd.SetOut(b)
    cmd.SetErr(b)
    err := cmd.Execute()
    fmt.Println(err)
    // do some asserts etc
}
```

I can run my entire test suite without issue:

```
go test -timeout 30s -run ^TestSuite$ my/package
```

But when I try to run this specific test the testify args are being passed to Cobra for some reason.

This:

```
go test -timeout 30s -run ^TestSuite$ -testify.m ^TestMyThing$ my/package
```

Returns this error:

```
unknown shorthand flag: 't' in -testify.m
```

It appears its parsing `-t` out of `-testify.m` and sending it to my Cobra app.

Why is this happening? From examples I see online my command is correct right? I tried re-ordering the params in various ways, but I see the same behavior.

## Edit

Ok I can merely set the args to null like this before calling Execute()

```
cmd.SetArgs([]string{""})
```

But I'm still confused about whats actually happening here. I guess I'm expecting testify to consume its own flags and not pass them along to the app like this. Is this expected behavior?

## Edit

So I added this to one of my tests and I think I know what might be happening here:

```
for _, element := range os.Args {
    println(element)
}
```

That gives me this output:

```
/tmp/go-build1970120879/b001/cmd.test
-test.testlogfile=/tmp/go-build1970120879/b001/testlog.txt
-test.paniconexit0
-test.v=test2json
-test.timeout=1m0s
-test.run=^TestSuite$
```

So I guess running go test with args is the same as running the actual application with args and Cobra is picking them up?

Reseting args with `SetArgs()` is perfectly fine, but now I'm curious if there is a native go test or testify feature designed to control which args make it to the actual app.